# XNA temporary pause

Tags: c#, xna, 2d-games

I need to do a temporary pause. If I do a collision with an enemy I want to pause the game for 1.5 seconds. Take a look here to my code:

```
bool tPause;
float timer;

public ovveride Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(!tPause)
        {
            //...
            if(enemy.rectangle.Intersects(player.rectangle))
            {
                timer+=(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                tPause=true;
                if(timer>1500)
                {
                    tPause=false;
                    timer=0;
                }
            }
            //...
        }
}
```

It doesn't function! What could I modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep updating the timer, even when the game is paused. Furthermore, I would count backwards:

```
if(timer <= 0) //!tPause
{
    //...
    if(enemy.rectangle.Intersects(player.rectangle))
    {
        timer = 1500; //initialize a 1.5 second pause
    }
}
else
    timer -= (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
```